# regex I am trying to find phone numbers with a missing 0

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a *.csv file open in **Notepad++**.  Sample data below.
I am trying to use the regular expression dialog from *Search/Replace* to find phone numbers which have a missing `0` at the beginning that would cause the phone number to be invalid.

Sample CSV file data (I have replaced the numbers with `#`s as I cannot post real numbers here):

```
PHONE,MOBILE
(0)1753 ######,0796#######
()1753 ######,0796#######
01702 #####,07966######
1702 #####,07966######
01698######,07966######
1698######,07966######
01389 ### ###,07966######
01268 ### ###,07966######
020 #### ####,07966######
20 #### ####,07966######
0288#######,07966######
0113 #######,07966#####
113 #######,07966#####
```

I started off with `[\d]{10}`. Not sure how I can macth the missing leading `0`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the data. Why do the numbers have differing lengths?

Comment: Can you use Excel or PowerShell instead?

Comment: Define "missing 0"? Many places, no (or few) valid phone numbers have a leading zero.

Comment: Some numbers with different lengths.  That is because some are invalid, some invalid numbers have come through into the csv file.  The user had not entered correctly from the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[1-9][0-9()]*\n**

This will match all rows not starting with a 0 and having digits or brackets in them.

Comment: The question appears to have two numbers per line. This will only match a number at the right-hand end of a line. It will also match the `1234567\n` part of `01234567\n`.

Comment: I cannot get any match with this regex, and currently provided text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to find all lines that start with `0`. The regex (Find field) should be `^0`.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In case you also want to check for `0` in front of each `,`, you should use `(^|,)0` regex:

[image]

Comment: @Peter you mean `^[^0]`. The regex `!0` just matches bang zero literally.

Comment: Hm some failed googling on my behalf. You're right.